# Print variables from a query in python

Tags: python

I make a query to the table mysql and then I make print of the variables:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.0.22", user="centro", passwd="qQQ!000p", db="centrodb")

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT Dias, HoraConsulta, HoraSaida, nome, Consulta, centrodb.LocalConsulta.Descricao, Contato FROM centrodb.RegistoConsultas LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.LocalConsulta ON centrodb.LocalConsulta.Id = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.`Local` LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.utentes ON centrodb.utentes.codigoutente = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.Utente LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.DiasSemana ON centrodb.DiasSemana.Id = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.DiaSemana")

myresult = cursor.fetchall()

for linha in myresult:
                dia = linha[Dias]
                hora = linha[HoraConsulta]
                saida = linha[HoraSaida]
                utente = linha[nome]
                consulta = linha[Consulta]
                local = linha[Descricao]
                contato =linha[Contato]

                print​ "Dia: " + dia
                print​ "Hora Consulta: " + hora
                print​ "Hora Saida: " + saida
                print​ "Utente: " + utente
                print​ "Consulta: " + consulta
                print​​ "Local: " + local
                print​ "Contato: " + contato

                except:
                print("Erro: Impossível obter dados")
```

when I run the script on ubuntu 16.04 terminal gives the following error:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: You've got some sort of invisible characters after every `print`. Get rid of those.

Comment: @ user2357112, How am I now starting in python how can I get rid of these invisible characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @user2357112, there seems to be an invisible character after print.

I copy and pasted your code on my IDE and it shows there is a invisible character and your would have to push backspace and you will notice that it will not delete the letter t but that hidden charcter.